# cloud9 on ubuntu getting ace.js 404 error in chrome

Tags: javascript, google-chrome, ubuntu-14.04, cloud9-ide

I have installed cloud9 on an ocean digital server 10.04 I installed it using the latest version from git

```
git clone https://github.com/ajaxorg/cloud9.git
```

and following the github install procedure:

[installation-and-usage](https://github.com/ajaxorg/cloud9#installation-and-usage)

The install went well and the server started successfully and runs in the browser:

```
~/cloud9/bin/cloud9.sh -l 0.0.0.0 --username user --password pass -w ~/workspace/myproject/
```

When I open it in Chrome, workspace loads correctly, I can see my files, but when I try to edit a file the editor window does not open.

Checking the network tab in Chrome developer tools I can see ace.js has a 404 error

```
Request URL:http://myname.com:3131/static/ace/build/ace.js
```

I then tried running it in Firefox and I can open and edit files without problems.

Can anyone suggest what the problem might be in Chrome?

Comment: Did you follow all required steps at https://github.com/ajaxorg/cloud9#installation-and-usage?

Comment: @NikolaiOnken Yes, I installed as recommended.  I will add this to the question.

Comment: I am having the exact same problem on Ubuntu...14.04

Answer (score 0):

Fixed for me by following the instructions at https://github.com/ajaxorg/cloud9/issues/3242

Comment: ajaxorg killed their repo. Anyone have a copy of the instructions that were in issue 3242?